# How to delete softwareupdate cache to download Catalina GM

Tags: macos, software-update, catalina

I tried multiple times to reboot, unenroll from beta, download new profile installer and tried to delete preferences. However, I still download Instalation where the Info.plist for `DTSDKBuild` key is `19A578c` which is beta 10.

Anyone knows other cache to delete or direct download url?

```
defaults remove com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate
defaults read com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate

Domain com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate does not exist

defaults read com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate
{
    LatestMajorOSSeenByUserBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.InstallAssistant.Seed.macOS1015Seed1";
    ProductKeysLastSeenByUser =     (
        "041-88937",
        "061-18973",
        "061-01542"
    );
}
```

> .SeedEnrollment.plist

```
sudo more /Users/Shared/.SeedEnrollment.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>SeedProgram</key>
        <string>DeveloperSeed</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image: info.plist]